# :set completeopt=menuone does not always show menu on the commandline

Tags: autocompletion, set, wildmenu

`:set completeopt=menuone` does not always show the menu. For example pressing `:vs<tab>` on the command line one would expect the menu to appear, with the singular option `vsplit`. What happens instead is `vsplit` is imediately completed. How can I prevent this, and instead always show the menu even with only one valid completion?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! We need more context, where are you using `vs<tab>`, on a script you're editing of type Vim? If so, are you using some plug-ins to enable and implement type completion? Or is it on the Vim command-line, like `:vs<tab>` to complete the Ex command you're typing, to have Vim execute it? Please [edit] the question to clarify the context where this completion is executed.

Comment: My bad! I've updated the question to reflect that this is a problem on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`'completeopt'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27completeopt%27) option only applies to [**Insert mode completion**](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#ins-completion), which is not really the case when you're completing an Ex command on the Vim command-line.

The completion menu on the Vim command-line is enabled by [`'wildmenu'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildmenu%27) and controlled with the [`'wildmode'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildmode%27) option.

But the `'wildmode'` option doesn't support any setting that will display the completion menu when there's a single candidate for completion. From `:help 'wildmode'`:

> When there is only a single match, it is fully completed in all cases.